# How to convert BigNumber to Number in Truffle framework?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, dapp-development, bignumber

I have written an ERC20 token contract and deployed it in test network using truffle framework. When I check the token balance for an account using web3 it was giving the result in BigNumber when I try to convert it to a number using toNumber() getting an unexpected result.

Solidity code:

```
  function balanceOf(address _from) constant public returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_from];
}
```

Javascript code:

```
instantiateBalance() {
const contract = require('truffle-contract')
const token = contract(Token)
token.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider)
var tokenInstance;
token.deployed().then(function(instance) {
tokenInstance = instance;
return tokenInstance.balanceOf.call("0xb1Cf866ced575FD1A1997Daa5d6F099efb282E41", {from: "0xb1Cf866ced575FD1A1997Daa5d6F099efb282E41"});
}).then(function(balance) {
console.log(balance.toNumber());
})
```

**Expected Result**

Decimals = 18

Actual Token Balance = 100000000.000000000000000000

**Actual Result**

Token Balance = 1000000000000

[image: Result:]

Comment: did you try balance.div(1e18) or balance.toNumber().div(1e18) ?

Comment: balance.div(1e18) will give me the digits before the decimal point. I need digits after decimal point also to display exact balance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### If your token have 18 decimals

like an ether you can use

```
then(function(balance) {
    console.log(web3.fromWei(balance.toNumber(), "ether" ) );
})
```

Use [fromWei](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3fromwei) to convert your bigNumber to ether and then convert it to Number. Be aware that unnecessary 0 after the floating point will not be displayed.

In web3 ^1.0 it may change to `web3.utils.fromWei` instead of `web3.fromWei` [doc](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#fromwei). Note that truffle ^5.0 uses web3 ^1.0.

### If you have a different token decimal

Let's say 6. You'll have to do the conversion manually with something like:

```
var tokenBalance = balance.ToNumber() / Math.pow(10, tokenDecimals)
```

Comment: I experienced a problem with this example, if the balance had 18 decimals it would strip it back to 16. To fix this I used `web3.fromWei(balance.toString(), "ether")`, notice `.toString()`. I'm unsure if this is best practice.

Comment: yes using toString() worked for me as well, when I used toNumber(), it gave me an error because we can not store that big number in that data type I think.

Comment: ToNumber not a function in truffle

Comment: @PhilipRego this was answered 3 years ago. It's obvious it changed now.

Comment: From Etherjs
BigNumber.from(bn).div(BigNumber.from(10).pow(decimal)).toNumber()

Answer (score 7):

You can use exponential number syntax in javascript to shorten you code.

#### Example (18 decimals):

```
const balance = getBalance().toNumber() / 1E18
```

PS. Sorry, i can not make comment due to low reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I like to work with big numbers and not parse them into "normal" numbers. I guess I'm afraid some overflow may happen if I don't.

Therefore, if a contract returns a `uint`, then I parse the return value to a `BigNumber` (from [bignumber.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/)), like so:

```
const balanceBefore = new BigNumber(await contract.getBalance(...));
```

and I like to use the `BigNumber` API for my assertions, like so:

```
assert(balanceBefore.minus(amountSent).minus(gasCost).isEqualTo(balanceAfter));
```

Comment: If you -1 please also add a comment with the reason why ... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A fast way could be

```
import web3 from 'web3';

const ethProvider = new web3(web3.givenProvider).eth;
const accounts = await ethProvider.requestAccounts();
const ethBalance = web3.utils.fromWei(await ethProvider.getBalance(accounts[0]), 'ether');
console.log(ethBalance);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just want log the balance, you should use

```json
    console.log(balance.toString());
```

instead.

It's throws genuine error that it can't fit the number in js `number` type.