# Truffle CMD Bignumber to number; hex to string

Tags: solidity, truffle, bignumber

A function in my contract when called on the truffle develop command line gives output in BigNumber format. 
Here is what I wrote on the command line:

```
instance = contract.at('deployed address')

instance.getAge()
```

I tried instance.getAge().toNumber() but that throws an error saying that toNumber isn't defined. I checked [How to convert BigNumber to Number in Truffle framework?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29597/how-to-convert-bignumber-to-number-in-truffle-framework) however that doesnt seem to work on command line.

Similary outputs from functions returning bytes32 are in hex.I checked [web3 return bytes32 string](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23058/web3-return-bytes32-string) but `web3.utils.toAscii(x) {x is any variable}`  throws an error

> "Cannot read property toAscii of undefined"

I read the stack related to that and that also didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Contract function calls in Truffle return [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) so you have to add a callback to get the response. If `getAge()` is declared as either `constant`, `pure` or `view` in the Solidity contract you can do `instance.getAge().then(age => age.toNumber())` if it doesn't have any of those modifiers then you need to do `instance.getAge.call().then(age => age.toNumber())`

Comment: Thanks!
I similarly had a function getname()that should return string but yields hex as output.
So for that should I type:

instance.getname().then(name => web3.toAscii(name))

?

Comment: No worries! Also you shouldn't have to convert the string return value of a function from hex. Is `getName()` declared with either `constant`, `view`, or `pure` after the function name as suggested above? If it isn't then consider adding it. If you can't add it for some reason use `instance.getname.call()` instead.

Comment: Ya it is constant
So I did `instance.getname().then(name => web3.toAscii(name))` . It did work, however it gave these strings of `\u0000` padded after the name. Anyway to remove that?

Comment: Where do you get the `instance` from? And does the function in Solidity return a string, eg it looks similar to this `function getName() constant returns (string)`?

Comment: `pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract MyFirst {

  bytes32 name;

  
  function set(bytes32 newName) public {
    name = newName;
  }

  
  function get() public constant returns (bytes32){
    return name;
  }
}`


I use bytes32 not string, because solidity doesnt function well with strings. It throws weird errors.

Comment: `bytes32` is a statically sized variable, so you won't be able to put a string into it that is larger than 32 bytes. `string` is a dynamically sized variable so you can put as large a string as you want in it. Unfortunately there are currently restrictions on passing dynamically sized variables, such as strings, between contracts and maybe between storage and memory which are probably the source of the weird errors. However, some of these limitations should be fixed in the next few months so hopefully you'll get less weird errors when using strings.

Comment: Sorry it was all a bit confusing. 

So this function getname - it should return bytes32. However, it instead returns hex. So I did `instance.getname().then(name => web3.toAscii(name))`. Now that works fine, except for a bit irritation coming from the padded `u0000`. Do you know a way to perhaps convert this hex output back to bytes32 without these `u0000`?

Comment: You can remove the trailing zeros with a regex before converting it to Ascii which could be done with `hexValue.replace(/0+$/, "")` so all of it together could look like this `instance.getname().then(hexValue => hexValue.replace(/0+$/, "")).then(hexNoTrailingZeros => web3.toAscii(hexNoTrailingZeros))`