# Convert big number to regular number

Tags: truffle

I call

`let inst = contract.deployed()`

and then on inst I can then call

`mybn = units.then(function(inst) {return inst.getBN()}`

mybn looks like this

`BN { negative: 0, words: [ 1, <1 empty item> ], length: 1, red: null }`

and if I run mybn.toNumber() I get the error letting me know `mybn.toNumber is not a function`

Comment: What is `units`? Is it a promise? It might be that `mybn` is not a `BN` but a promise instead, using `await` should resolve it.

Comment: Here it is explained well enough. [https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/29610/50610](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/29610/50610)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is going to work because I don't understand the question fully. But Please try this.

First you can try using:

```
web3.utils.isBN(bn)
```

Then go to the following if it returns true.

**var BN = web3.utils.BN;**

**new BN(1234).toString();**

> "1234"

**new BN('1234').add(new BN('1')).toString();**

> "1235"

**new BN('0xea').toString();**

> "234"

reference:
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#bn